# RefreshScope in Spring reloadsonly singletons

Tags: spring, spring-boot

is it possible to refresh a prototype bean using @RefreshScope annotation? I`ve noticed that when a component is a singleton then there is a possibility to refresh it (a bean instance is wrapped by an aspect). But when I try to use @RefreshScope annotation on a bean marked as a prototype then its autowired instance is not a proxy just a normal bean instance which cannot be refreshed.
So, the question is: does this mechanism (bean refreshment) work with singletons only? Is it possible to use it with a prototypes?
Thanks